# Why is maxima showing only [ ] as output answer?

Tags: maxima-software

I'm new at using maxima, so when I wanted to solve these simultaneous equations $$y_1=-\left(\frac{2ax+c+ey}{2by+d+ex}\right)x_1+\left[y+\left(\frac{2ax+c+ey}{2by+d+ex}\right)x\right]$$
and, $$ax^2+by^2+cx+dy+exy+f=0$$
where the variables are $x,y$, maxima showed $[\;]$ as the otput. I inserted the system of equation through the solve algebraic system option available under the equation option in the status bar of the GUI wxmaxima. So what should I do to get a proper answer as output, please suggest.

Comment: usually you cannot just throw a bunch of letters in a CAS and expect sense. You might try assigning number values to all the letters other than $x,y,$ asking for output of the same system

Comment: you should post the command that maxima executes